# Add Nested Reactive FormArray within FormArray - Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, multidimensional-array, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am attempting to add multiple inputs inside of a table row using nested Reactive Forms in Angular 6. I am having trouble pushing to a Form Array within a Form Array in typescript. I have added my full code (including a dummy service to pull in data) to a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ewxe5)

How can I implement adding to the productCombination form array inside of my `addProductCombination()` method. The desired behavior is that the table row in which the 'plus' button is clicked will have a new select/input element for each form control inside of my productCombination FormArray. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an `AbstractFormControl` instance from a `FormArray` using the `at` method on it.

So here's how you can break down the things that you'll have to do:

1. Get the `records` `FormArray` from your Reactive Form.
2. Call the `at` method on it this `FormArray` and pass it the index that you want to get the `AbstractControl` instance from. I've used `0` for example.
3. This will yield the `AbstractControl` instance inside which, you have the `productCombination` `FormArray`. So you'll now need to have access to that. That's what `(<FormArray>formControl.get('productCombination'))` is doing.
4. Once you get the inner FormArray, you can call the `push` method on it and pass it the `AbstractControl` instance you want to add to it.

So in code, it would look something like:

```
addProductCombination() {
  let formControl = ( < FormArray > this.productBlendCodeForm.get('records')).at(0);
  ( < FormArray > formControl.get('productCombination')).push(this.initProductCombinations({}));
}
```